# Node fs.readFile function

Tags: node.js

I am new to node and I am trying to understand the fs.readFile() function. The documentation says it can accept the parameters.

fs.readFile(path[, options], callback).

The documentation provides this simple example.

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

My question is, does the "err" parameter need to be called "err" or can it be any name like "foo". And if it can be any name, how does the code know to pass an actual error onto this parameter?

Comment: In Javascript, you can name the parameters to a callback anything you want.  Those names are for you to choose in your callback code.  They must be positioned properly because the first parameter will be the error value and the second parameter will be the data value (no matter what you name them).  That said `err` is a popular convention in Javascript for the asynchronous error indicator and your code will conform to other code if you call it `err` or `error`.

Answer (score 0):

With the callback pattern in JavaScript, the first parameter is typically reserved for an error that may be encountered during the execution of the underlying function. It can be any arbitrary string you like, but it's best practice to use some meaningful name. The second parameter, `data`, below is the input from the file being read if no error has occurred.

e.g.

```
const fsReadFile = (fileName) => {
    fileName = `${__dirname}/${fileName}`
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
            if (!error && data) {
                resolve(data)
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    })
}
```